# How to convert php variable to float, after it was obtained by javascript? Php's (float) casting function is returning 0 and not converting

Tags: javascript, php, type-conversion, optionsettype

I'll be obtaining jsvariable from on onclick javascript from the user. The user will input how much money they are spending in $xx.xx amount. It will come in, in string form. I need to do math on the amount, so I need it as a float.

I set it to a string as an example. I extract it from javascript into a php string variable:

```
<script> var jsvariable = "2.25"; </script> 

<?php $x = "<script>document.writeln(jsvariable);</script>";
 echo $x;  var_dump($x); ?>
```

The echo $x shows 2.25. The var_dump shows that $x is a string(38) "2.25 " 
So it's showing the $x variable now in php to be a 38 char string but it contains only 5 characters.

Then I try converting it with settype function. Also try re-casting it. It's not converting it.

```
<?php 
settype($x, "float"); 
echo "After settype x is "; echo $x; var_dump($x);

$y = (float)$x ; 
echo " y cast y is "; echo $y; var_dump ($y);
?>
```

After settype x is 0 float(0)

After casting y is 0 float(0)

How do I convert the $x string into a float number that's the right value of 2.25 ?

Comment: I am skipping the retrieval code in part because I haven't fully worked it out yet though I have a good start. Also because even if I learn a better way to do this such as a way to get js to read in as numeric.... it's bugging me that the settype isn't working as I'd expect.

Comment: `$x` is a string with HTML tags, although it will echo 2.25 to a browser, trying to convert this to a float will fail.

Comment: When $x = "<script>document.writeln(jsvariable);</script>", then $x is never "2.25" and can not be casted to a float of 2.25. it is one, because casting true to a number will result in 1.

Comment: How do I then string the html tags and make $x into a string that can be converted to a number?

Comment: Have you read the docs? `settype Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure`

Comment: Read what docs? I put that phrase into google. So I see it's boolean. Thank you. But I'd already tried $x and it wasn't converting.  Example: $y = (float)$x  is giving a 0 rather than the 2.25. I'm lost on what to look up or where???

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it like this: `$y = (float)$x`. You might want to check out [type juggeling](https://www.php.net/language.types.type-juggling) as well as [String conversion to numbers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Comment: $y = (float)$x ; set $y to 0. It added fine so it's a number. But it's still not 2.25. Thanks for the links. I'll read them.

Comment: I just tested. It's converting the javascript obtained string to boolean. Instead of float.